# Why does my rails automatically decode URL? How can I stop it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I was trying to fetch a URL like this:

```
http://myweb/api/1/1/NJUimQw0bsJgv%2FqjfpMzCl5CeeL%2BnCQr61UVLBcJCNA%3D%0A
```

However, the log file shows:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/1/1/NJUimQw0bsJgv/qjfpMzCl5CeeL+nCQr61UVLBcJCNA=%0A"):
```

It seems that rails automatically decodes URI. How can I disable it?

In my route.rb:

```
scope '/api' do
  get '/:aid/:uid/:token' => 'my_apis#show'
end
```

My website is rails 4.2.1 and is using nginx.

Comment: Could it be your browser fixing the URL?

Comment: So `aid` should be `1`, `uid` should be `1`, and `token` should be all the rest? Have you tried adding a constraint to the route to tell Rails to keep its dirty hands of your slashes?

Comment: TO  user12341234: Browser fail also. TO Hardik: I had tried restarting it but still don't work. What is the environment parameter may cause this problem?
To mu is too short: I didn't add a constraint, How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your token contains forward slash('/') which is causing the issue, modify the route which will solve the issue

```
scope '/api' do
  get '/:aid/:uid/:token' => 'my_apis#show', constraints: { token: /.*/ }
end
```

[segment-constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) restricts the format of the dynamic segment using regular expression, in your case the dynamic segment is `token`. The Regexp `/.*/` matches each character (including forward slash `/`)

So overall it tells rails that every character after `uuid` is `token`. so rails includes `/` in token as well

Comment: Thanks!! It works perfectly. Can I ask how does "constraints: { token: /.*/ }" work?